# How to get OEM information via Python-dmidecode module

Tags: python, linux, dmi

How do I retrieve dmidecode (type 204) information using Python dmidecode module?

I'm using Linux Redhat on HP Hardware.

Here's what I'm looking for (except that I want it via Python):

```
> dmidecode --type 204

# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0xCC00, DMI type 204, 20 bytes
HP ProLiant System/Rack Locator
        Rack Name: UnnamedRack
        Enclosure Name: encdrp5
        Enclosure Model: BladeSystem c7000 Enclosure G3
        Enclosure Serial: xxxxxxxxx
        Enclosure Bays: 16
        Server Bay: 6
        Bays Filled: 1
```

I've tried this:

```
import dmidecode

dmidecode.type(204)
```

But I've got `{}`

Comment: for dmidecode you need read permission on /dev/mem. does your user have that?

Comment: I'm using root, but anyway it's not a permission issue because i can fetch the information using "dmidecode" from the cli.
it's more like unfeatured from python side.

Comment: looks like it will only decode types it can convert to xml using the file `/usr/share/python-dmidecode/pymap.xml` (on my setup).

Comment: Dmidecode has a dict that maps type to name and drops all sections that are not in the map. That seams bizarre to me. 204 is an hp specific section so I can't test it but the offending line in parse_dmi is pretty obvious. Try removing it to see how it goes.

Comment: Can you give an example for how to do that?

Comment: Actually my final goal is to obtain HP Facts like "Enclosure Name" and "Server Bay" via  [tag:Ansible]. Any suggestions?